# Как правильно создать свое правило UrlRules?

Tags: yii2

Попытался создать свое правило:

```
namespace frontend\components;

class SerialsUrlRule extends Object implements UrlRuleInterface
{
    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {

        if ($route === 'serial/category/oneserial') {

            if (isset($params['id']))
                return 'serials/' . $params['id'];

        } elseif ($route === 'serial/category/list') {

            if (isset($params['slug']))
                return 'serials/' . $params['slug'];
        }

        return false;  // данное правило не применимо
    }

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {

            $path = $matches[0];

            if ($path == 'serial/category/oneserial') {

                $exists = Serial::find()
                    ->where([
                        'slug_serial' => $matches[1]
                    ])->exists();

                if ($exists)
                    return  ['serial/category/oneserial', 'id' => $matches[1]];
            }

            if ($path == 'serial/category/list') {

                $exists = Category::find()
                    ->where([
                        'slug_category' => $matches[1]
                    ])->exists();

                if($exists)
                    return  ['serial/category/list','slug'=>$matches[1]];
            }
        }
        return false;  
    }
}
```

В config/main.php подключил так

```
[
    'class' => 'frontend\components\SerialsUrlRule',
],
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы ссылка `<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/oneserial','id'=>$model->slug_serial])?>` парсилась так serials/serial-nazvanie, и она так и парсится но при этом но при этом возникает ошибка 404.

Также хотелось бы, чтобы `Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/list','slug'=>$ct->slug_category])` парсило такую ссылку serials/nazvanie-category происходит тоже самое парсится выдает 404 ошибку

Экшены:

```
public function actionList($slug=null){
    $model = Serial::findOne(['slug_serial'=>$id]);
    //...
}

public function actionList($slug=null){
    if ($slug == null) {
        $categoryThe = Category::find()->all();
    } else {
        $categoryThe = Category::findOne(['slug_category' => $slug]);
    }
    //..., использую avtivedataprovider
}
```

Comment: Третий вопрос по этим вашим сериалам плодите и не хотите развивать диалог. Зачем все это?

Comment: @zabachok сериалы одни принципы реализации разные

Comment: Пожалуйста ставьте знаки препинания, иначе очень тяжело понимать эти кучки слов.

Comment: @zabachok давайте нашу перепалку закончим в ней нет смысла, заранее спасибо.